# Не загружается GUI (Xubuntu)

Tags: linux, xubuntu, x11, xfce

Ноутбук Lenovo Ideapad i7, Nvidia Geforce GTX
ОС - Xubuntu 20.04
Ноуту полгода, до сегодняшнего дня проблем не было.

Диск зашифрован при установке ОС, подключён внешний монитор.
В нормальном состоянии загрузка происходила так:

- Появляется графическая заставка. Please unlock...
- Ввожу пароль от диска
- Пишет cryptsetup: set up successfully
- Через время появляется плашка для логина и подключается внешний монитор

Теперь начало происходить следующее

- Please unlock, пароль, set up successfully - всё по прежнему (ещё пишет press ctrl+c to cancel all filesystem checks, но это он и так часто пишет)
- Однако, дальше дисплей ноутбука так и остаётся с этой заставкой
- На внешнем же мониторе появляется плашка логина и дальше всё работает на нём
- В settings -> displays виден только внешний монитор
- За полчаса до этого всё включалось нормально, никаких обновлений не ставил

Далее:

- Я как самый умный, думаю - выдерну внешний монитор и перезагружусь
- Ясное дело, ничего не изменилось и теперь внешний монитор обратно не подключается, остался только дисплей ноутбука с висящей заставкой
- Alt+Ctrl+F(1..6) переключают на терминалы, в них всё работает, только сети нет
- Alt+Ctrl+F(7...) ничего не дают, только подвисает всё на некоторое время

Вопросы:

- Куда копать, какие логи и на предмет чего смотреть?
- Как хотя бы вернуть внешний монитор из консоли?
- Как хотя бы включить сеть из консоли?

PS: до этого был открыт эмулятор android, с ним и начались проблемы "AWD manager was killed...", решил перезагрузить и началось вышеописанное

**UPDATE**

- В Xord.0.log есть несколько warning, папок шрифтов нет и подобное, но я посмотрел на другом рабочем ноутбуке, там они тоже есть в логах
- Сервис lighdm работает, в статусе есть warningи типа unable dlopen(pam_kwallet), однако, на работающем ноутбуке они идентичины
- Xorg -configure ничего не меняет
- xrandr на всё отвечает Can't open display

**РЕШЕНО**

В итоге пришлось вспомнить старые времена на Windows и решить проблемы переустановкой системы.

Comment: Читайте логи Xorg

Comment: драйвер нвидии если стоит, то в нем потыкайте

Comment: лучше будет если вы скопируете решение проблемы в поле "Ваш ответ", отправите его и примите галочкой слева

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov ну так себе решение проблемы. Это как если бы на вопрос "Как сложить два числа на JS?" ответить "Передумал использовать JS, сложил в уме".

Comment: @mkkik абсолютно согласен, но висящий вопрос ни к чему, а улучшить вопрос, чтобы дать действительно стоящий ответ похоже не представляется возможным

Comment: @mkkik Нормальный ответ. Работает ⇒ не трогай ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге пришлось вспомнить старые времена на Windows и решить проблемы переустановкой системы.

Comment: "Сколько винду не ставь, а все равно переставлять придется" (c) → "Сколько что-угодно не ставь, а все равно переставлять придется" ;D

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, не для «что-угодно». вот я свои рабочие/домашние системы вообще ни разу не переустанавливал (ну, после того, как в самом начале потыкался в разные дистрибутивы, и остановился на *debian gnu/linux*). например, система с прошлого места работы прожила 8 лет на работе и уже 3 года дома (выполняя функции nas), за это время пережив несколько смен материнских плат и винчестеров. // т.е., на моём примере, железо горит/устаревает/меняется гораздо чаще, чем установленная операционная система.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin У меня руки менее прямые чем у вас ;) При чем `"Сколько винду не ставь, а все равно переставлять придется" (c) → "Сколько что-угодно не ставь, а все равно переставлять придется" ;D ` это шутка. Я давно ничего не переставлял тоже.  ;D Хотя провести 8 лет вообще как-то постоянно, даже не на уровне установок — это да ;)